# SilverStripe DropdownField populated by js - [value] is not a valid option

Tags: silverstripe

I've got a SilverStripe form which includes a dropdown field displayed on the front-end of my website.

```
$fields = new FieldList(
    ...
    DropdownField::create(
        'Employer',
        'Employer'
    )
    ...
);


....

$actions = new FieldList(
    FormAction::create('doReportIssue')->setTitle('Report')
);

$required = new RequiredFields('FirstName', 'LastName');

$form = new Form($this, 'ReportIssueForm', $fields, $actions, $required);

return $form;
```

I've got some javascript which sets the options in the dropdown.

```
 let employerEl = $("#Form_ReportIssueForm_Employer");
 let employers = [{ "name":"employerA" }, { "name":"employerB" }];
 employers.forEach((employer) => {
     employerEl.append($("<option></option>").val(employer.name).text(employer.name));
     });
 });
```

The field is generated correctly in the form, and the javascript correctly populates the options.

However, when I submit the form I get the message

> Please select a value within the list provided.
>   employerA is not a valid option

I don't need this field to be validated server-side.
How do I stop this behaviour from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out a solution, but I'm sure there's a more elegant SilverStripe way of doing it.

I extended the DropdownField class, and made `validate` always return true.

```
class NoValidationDropdownField extends DropdownField {
    public function validate($validator)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```